# What font is used in this computer academy certificate? Check the attached image

Tags: fonts, text, font-identification

I am trying to find the font of text "Creative COMPUTER" that surrounds the logo. **They are two different fonts, I need both of them.**
Guys I have already **tried all the online font identification resources**, from *font matcherator* from *fontspring* to *Artworkfontfinder* from *bizongo*. All sites failed because the text is written in *round/curved* line. The certificate is from 2005-6 so the font is not new but also very common. Help me identify the font or some similar font like that.
Thanks...
[image]

Comment: Which font are you looking for? ‘Creative’ or ‘COMPUTER’? They’re different fonts (the latter looks like Monotype Cursiva at first glance to me).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet thank you Janus for identifying Monotype Cursia. I am actually remaking the logo so I need both the fonts, the "Creative" as well as the "COMPUTER" which you already identified.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Trick - lasso then copy/paste individual letters, straighten then search the result. What The Font is pretty lenient on imprecision, once they're straight-ish...

> [image]

It has to be said, though, that certificate is good reason to employ a designer next time. Is that **five** different fonts I can see in just one corner of it?

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin for the great trick that I will definitely use next time and yeah the above certificate is bit old and was probably designed by an amateur. Thank you again for helping me to identify the font. Looking forward to help you in the future if I can.

Comment: WhatTheFont is definitely lenient on precision, at the cost of not always getting the correct identification at the top of the list.  And the best part is if the automated bot can't get it, you can submit it to the forum where you're likely to get a perfect answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Maybe the intention was to make it harder to fake them ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin is there anything you CAN'T do?

Comment: @spikey_richie - Juggle. Unicycle. Fly a plane. Lots of things ;))